# Scala parameterization of my array assumes a String?

Tags: scala, parameterization

I've read up a little on Manifests and the erasure-avoidance techniques required to allow Scala to do things like "new Array[Array[T]]", but I'm a little stumped with this one....

I've got a method that sort of tabulates up a bunch of rows in an array like a spreadsheet.  For example imagine a 2D array like this:

```
11,   5,    4
8,    3,    7
2,    1,    4
```

I wrote a method that sums up the columns of that array and spits out a 1D array like [21, 9, 15]

I want to genericize it beyond just Ints (like Doubles or Floats maybe), and when I add a parameter and manifest I get a compile error.

Here's the code

```
def sumGrid[T](grid: Array[Array[T]])(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]): Array[T] = {

  val sum = new Array[T](grid(0).size)

  for(i <- 0 until grid.size) {
    for(j <- 0 until grid(0).size) {
      sum(j) = sum(j) + grid(i)(j)
    }
  }  
  sum
}
```

Here's the compile error:

```
[ERROR] ...scala/euler/GridOperations.scala:126: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : T
[INFO]  required: String
[INFO]         sum(j) = sum(j) + grid(i)(j)
[INFO]                                  ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

What's going on here?  Why is String "required"?

Comment: Note that in this case you can sidestep the issue by writing `def sumGrid[T: Numeric](grid: Array[Array[T]]) = grid.transpose.map(_.sum)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you use the `+` operator which is always defined for strings. Any type can be converted to String (`toString` is always defined) and thus it will work for any type `T`.

But you could add some constraints on `T` to ensure it corresponds to the arithmetic operation. For instance, you can use implicits to get a `Numeric` objects defining the addition for type `T`:

```
def sumGrid[T](grid: Array[Array[T]])
(implicit m: ClassManifest[T], num: Numeric[T]): Array[T] = {

  val sum = new Array[T](grid(0).size)

  for(i <- 0 until grid.size) {
    for(j <- 0 until grid(0).size) {
      sum(j) = num.plus( sum(j), grid(i)(j) )
    }
  }  
  sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You handled the `Array` part, but `T` doesn't have any constrains that say it has a `+` method. Because of that, Scala thinks you are adding strings -- it will auto-convert any type to a `String` when you add it to another `String`. So it auto-converted `sum(j)` to `String`, and now expects `grid(i)(j)` to be another `String`, at which point it gives up and fails.

You can handle the thing about `T` being numeric in a similar manner to the `ClassManifest` stuff. Here:

```
// I'm using the "context bound" notation, to make the declaration shorter and
// more obvious on what I'm saying about T
def sumGrid[T : ClassManifest : Numeric](grid: Array[Array[T]]): Array[T] = {
  // the following line, plus the Numeric bound, makes T usable as a number
  import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._

  val sum = new Array[T](grid(0).size)

  for(i <- 0 until grid.size) {
    for(j <- 0 until grid(0).size) {
      sum(j) = sum(j) + grid(i)(j)
    }
  }  
  sum
}
```